# twig - Include block

Tags: twig

I have templates:
**base.html.twig** with content:

```
<body>
    <section class="main-content">
        <div class="content">
            {% embed "_partials/page_header.html.twig" %}
                {% block page_header_h1 %}{% endblock %}
                {% block page_header_h2 %}{% endblock %}
            {% endembed %}
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

**page_header.html.twig**   with content:

```
<div class="text-wrapper typo alt center">
    <h1>{% block page_header_h1 %}{% endblock %}</h1>
    <h2>{% block page_header_h2 %}{% endblock %}</h2>
</div>
```

and on sub-pages I'm doing (e.g. **profile.html.twig**)

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block page_header_h1 %}My profile{% endblock %}
{% block page_header_h2 %}Here are details of your profile{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    content of the page
{% endblock %}
```

but on `page_header.html.twig` I'm not getting these values, why?

Comment: Can't be done. When `including` or `embedding` templates the information about `blocks` is not passed down to do the caller. The block are therefor unknown to the caller, meaning that the caller can't alter the blocks.

Comment: @DarkBee Do you have any idea how to do somethink like this?

Comment: If you want them in page_header.html.twig, you cant put them there. Is there any reason you don't do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are making it yourself that difficult. You could easily avoid this by going with the next approach:

```
<div class="text-wrapper typo alt center">
    {% if page_header_h1 | default('') | trim != '' %}
    <h1>{{ page_header_h1 }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
    {% if page_header_h2 | default('') | trim != '' %}
    <h2>{{ page_header_h2  }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

And pass the titles in your controller

```
$twig->render('profile.html.twig', [
    'page_header_h1' => 'My profile',
    'page_header_h2' => 'Here are details of your profile',  
]);
```